# Xamarin OxyPlot Upgrade Missing Function and File Path

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, oxyplot

I have an old project that running on the old VS (2017) and currently trying to run in vs2022 so I trying to upgrade. I got multiple error and related to the OxyPlot. Here are the error.

First error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Invalid value 'armeabi' in $(AndroidSupportedAbis). This ABI is no longer supported. Please update your project properties to remove the old value. If the properties page does not show an 'armeabi' checkbox, un-check and re-check one of the other ABIs and save the changes.   OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android
```

Second error:

```
Error       The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android (v9.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (10.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.    OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
```

So the first error about the `SupportedAbis` I have handled by changing the `.csproj` from

```
`<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi</AndroidSupportedAbis>`
```

to

```
<AndroidSupportedAbis>x86_64</AndroidSupportedAbis>
```

The problem seems fine but after I `clean` and `rebuild` another error comes as below

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       invalid file path '...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android\obj\Debug\100\res\main.xml'. OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android
```

For the second error. I have changed the `project properties -> application -> compile using Adnroid version: (Target Framework) to Android 10.0`. After `clean` and `rebuild` the error multiply and going crazy as below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  6   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ExportRendererAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  9   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ExportRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  9   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PlotView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  9   Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'OxyPlot.Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?) OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  15  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ViewRenderer<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  20  Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'PlotView' does not exist in the namespace 'OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  20  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PlotView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  20  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ElementChangedEventArgs<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  51  Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'PlotView' does not exist in the namespace 'OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android  ...\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlotViewRenderer.cs  51  Active
```

PlotViewRenderer.cs

```
using Android.Content;
using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;
using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using global::Xamarin.Forms;
using global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

// Exports the renderer.
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PlotView), typeof(PlotViewRenderer))]

namespace OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android;

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a custom <see cref="OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.PlotView" /> renderer for Xamarin.Android. 
    /// </summary>
    public class PlotViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.PlotView, PlotView>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="PlotViewRenderer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        static PlotViewRenderer()
        {
            Init();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PlotViewRenderer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public PlotViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            // Do not delete
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the renderer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>This method must be called before a <see cref="T:PlotView" /> is used.</remarks>
        public static void Init()
        {
            OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.PlotView.IsRendererInitialized = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the element changed event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The event arguments.</param>
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.PlotView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var plotView = new PlotView(this.Context)
            {
                Model = this.Element.Model,
                Controller = this.Element.Controller
            };

            plotView.SetBackgroundColor(this.Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());

            this.SetNativeControl(plotView);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the element property changed event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The event arguments.</param>
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.PlotView.ModelProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                this.Control.Model = this.Element.Model;
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.PlotView.ControllerProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                this.Control.Controller = this.Element.Controller;
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                this.Control.SetBackgroundColor(this.Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have tried to `clean project` and then delete bin and obj folder, close the VS and reopened and rebuild. It is still remains error.

Any idea? Thank in advance.

Comment: Try making a new xamarin project, add oxyplot, see if you can get that to work / or if you get fewer errors. Add a new section to question showing what happens in that case. Goal is to get that building first (even if it doesn't do anything useful). Then compare `.csproj` files of original and new projects. Or add your original source files to the new project.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for your advice, I have tried the solution. Yes, the goal is to make fewer errors first and building the app. I have read several articles on the internet and said that this is a bug from the VS since I use a shared library. Is it true? Furthermore, I got another error here  `JAR library references with identical file names but different contents were found` and no idea what happened with the code since it is an old project. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the nuget package( OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms ) you mentioned. It's too old and not compatible with the .net maui project.

So you need to remove the reference of it when you update your project from xamarin forms to .net maui.

Or you can refer to the this document about [Using Custom Renderers in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) to migrate the PlotView and the PlotViewRenderer manually.